# Retrieve file owner email of Google Drive files

Tags: google-apps-script

I’m looking to use Drive API v3 with appscript to look up the owners. created date, current sharing settings of drive files by a list of file ids (listed in column A) and print the output to Column B.

Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. Because from your question, I couldn't notice about `what if - as a super admin in a google workspace enterprise environment, i can retrieve file owners for any files in the domain using this method with the 'owners' field developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get. how do you implement it in the sample script?`. So I have to delete my answer. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike, it was extremely helpful! thank you. it was my bad to ask an additional question instead of creating a new post. for the original question with your solution, how do i add a column to include date created with getDateCreated method?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your new question, your `what if - as a super admin in a google workspace enterprise environment, i can retrieve file owners for any files in the domain using this method with the 'owners' field developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get. how do you implement it in the sample script?` is not included?

Comment: correct, it was just a 'nice to have' :) i posted a new question that's more clear :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `correct, it was just a 'nice to have' :) i posted a new question that's more clear :)`, in this case, how will you do this you question? Where should I post the answer?

Comment: [new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71290257/retrieve-drive-file-information-by-id-with-appscript) thank you! @Tanaike

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use Apps Script you can use the following function:

```
function myFunction() {

var spreadsheetId = "###";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
console.log(ss.getOwner().getEmail())

}
```

Please note that the code would give you error messages if you do not have access to the files. This is expected due to security reasons. Sharing permissions would need to be at least for anyone within the domain to have access to the file.