# Retrieve drive file information by ID with appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Retrieve drive file information of Google Drive files and list in Google Sheet

I’m looking to use appscript to look up the owners, file created date, current sharing settings of drive files by a list of file ids, with file IDs listed in column A, row by row of the sheet and the outcome would print the informations in separate columns in the row (column B for owner, C for created date, D for current sharing settings).

Is this possible?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `current sharing settings` you expect. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: And, in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71259523), after I posted an answer, you added the question of `what if - as a super admin in a google workspace enterprise environment, i can retrieve file owners for any files in the domain using this method with the 'owners' field developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get. how do you implement it in the sample script?`. Can I ask you about the relationship between your this question and the added question in your previous question?

Comment: @Tanaike for current sharing settings, i meant [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getsharingaccess)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike for my added question, there's no relationship. it was just an additional possibility to check on files that the script runner doesnt have access to but does when it's executed in a company domain where the runner of the script is a domain admin. please ignore my added question, it's no longer relevant :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your latest reply.

Comment: dont worry, your english is great! my question is just confusing, i apologize. Let me explain, so in your last answer, i was able to get the owner email in column b. I would like to add more columns with Column C being 'created date of the file', column D being the [Enum Access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access) of the file by using the [getSharingAccess()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getsharingaccess) method. Hope that's clear, let me know if you have any questions. thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @pyth0nnoOb Please refrain from asking the same question multiple times; just click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71259523/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file IDs from the column "A" of the Spreadsheet and want to retrieve the owner's email, the created date, the current sharing settings (the value of ["Enum Access"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access)) of the file and put it to column "B", "C" and "D".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the sheet name, and run `myFunction` at the script editor.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow == 0) return;
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + lastRow);
  const values = range.getValues().map(([id]) => {
    try {
      const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
      const owner = file.getOwner();
      const createdDate = file.getDateCreated();
      const sharing = file.getSharingAccess().toString();
      return [owner ? owner.getEmail() : "", createdDate, sharing];
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
      return Array(3).fill("");
    }
  });
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the file IDs are retrieved from the column "A", the owner (email address), the created date, the sharing setting of the file is retrieved, and those values are put from the column "B".
- When the owner cannot be retrieved, the empty value is put.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, from your question, it supposes that the file IDs are put to the column "A". If the column "A" is not the file ID, the file metadata cannot be retrieved. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: thank you! i ran it and am getting this error even though I have access to all the files listed 'Error 
Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it.
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:9
myFunction @ Code.gs:8'

Comment: @pyth0nnoOb Thank you for replying, I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, the file metadata cannot be retrieved from such a file. In that case, how about skipping such IDs? For this, I modified my sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I got it to work @tanaike, thank you so much for all of your help!